# Changing Culture at runtime in Windows Store apps (Windows 8.1)

Tags: c#, localization, windows-store-apps

I am trying to localize an app in Arabic Language. I am able to accomplish LTR / RTL but I am unable to change the Culture / UICulture in Windows Store Apps (**Windows 8.1 Preview**) without restarting the app.

I tried the following but unable to achieve my objective:

1. Changed
   `Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride`
   and set it to my desired language, `"ar-AE"`and navigated to the same frame `frame.Navigate(frame.Content.GetType());`
2. I also tried changing the `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`
   and`DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture`
3. I tried resetting the Global Qualifier Values of an app using        `ResourceManager.Current.DefaultContext.QualifierValues.MapChanged
           += QualifierValues_MapChanged;`

I have already had a word with few friends from Microsoft but I am not able to get an answer for that. I want to know how can it be done (if there's a way to do that?)

[My previous discussion with Tim Heuer and Tareq Ateik.](https://twitter.com/arafattehsin/status/373809566380994560)

Thanks

Comment: Well I guess you are using Backgroundworker/Threads. DefaultThreadCurrentCulture only sets the culture for one thread, not the whole application. There is currently no workaround for this. €: I can't access Twitter from my location

Comment: But this `Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride` is for the whole app and I used that as well.

Comment: I've managed to work with that; you can check out this blog post of mine to achieve - http://www.radlabs.biz/blog/dynamic-localization-winrt.html